# Numpy genfromtxt iterate over columns

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I am using `NumPy`'s `genfromtext` to get columns from a CSV file.

Each column needs to be split and assigned to a separate `SQLAlchemy` `SystemRecord` combined with some other columns and attributes and added to the DB.

Whats the best practice to iterate over the columns `f1` to `f9` and add them to the session object?

So far, I have used the following code but I don't want to do the same thing for each `f` column:

```
t = np.genfromtxt(FILE_NAME,dtype=[(np.str_, 20),(np.str_, 20),(np.str_, 20),(np.str_, 20),(np.str_, 20),(np.str_, 20),(np.str_, 20),(np.str_, 20), (np.str_, 20), (np.str_, 20),(np.str_, 20)]\
 ,delimiter=',',filling_values="None", skiprows=0,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))

for r in enumerate(t):
    _acol = r['f1'].split('-')
    _bcol = r['f2'].split('-')
    ....
    arec = t_SystemRecords(first=_acol[0], second=_acol[1], third=_acol[2], ... )
    db.session.add(arec)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: wouldn't be possible to iterate over the transpose of `t`, just doing: `for col in t.T: ...` ?

Comment: thats interesting - I will try it

Comment: Generally (always?) `genfromtxt` produces a 1d array structured array.  `transpose` does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `t.dtype`.  Or the `r.dtype`.

Make a sample structured array (which is what genfromtxt returns):

```
t = np.ones((5,), dtype='i4,i4,f8,S3')
```

which looks like:

```
array([(1, 1, 1.0, b'1'), (1, 1, 1.0, b'1'), (1, 1, 1.0, b'1'),
       (1, 1, 1.0, b'1'), (1, 1, 1.0, b'1')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', 'S3')])
```

the `dtype` and `dtype.names` are:

```
In [135]: t.dtype
Out[135]: dtype([('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', 'S3')])

In [138]: t.dtype.names
Out[138]: ('f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3')
```

iterate over the names to see the individual columns:

```
In [139]: for n in t.dtype.names:
   .....:     print(t[n])
   .....:     
[1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
[b'1' b'1' b'1' b'1' b'1']
```

Or in your case, iterate over the 'rows', and then iterate over the names:

```
In [140]: for i,r in enumerate(t):
   .....:     print(r)
   .....:     for n in r.dtype.names:
   .....:         print(r[n])
   .....:         
(1, 1, 1.0, b'1')
1
1
1.0
b'1'
(1, 1, 1.0, b'1')
...
```

---

For `r`, which is 0d (check `r.shape`), you can select items by number or iterate

```
r[1]  # == r[r.dtype.names[1]]
for i in r: print(r)
```

For `t` which is 1d this does not work; `t[1]` references an item.

1d structured arrays behave a bit like 2d arrays, but not quite.  The usual talk of `row` and `column` has to be replaced with `row` (or item) and `field`.

---

To make a `t` that might be closer to your case

```
In [175]: txt=[b'one-1, two-23, three-12',b'four-ab, five-ss, six-ss']

In [176]: t=np.genfromtxt(txt,dtype=[(np.str_,20),(np.str_,20),(np.str_,20)])

In [177]: t
Out[177]: 
array([('one-1,', 'two-23,', 'three-12'),
       ('four-ab,', 'five-ss,', 'six-ss')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U20'), ('f1', '<U20'), ('f2', '<U20')])
```

`np.char` has string functions that can be applied to an array:

```
In [178]: np.char.split(t['f0'],'-')
Out[178]: array([['one', '1,'], ['four', 'ab,']], dtype=object)
```

It doesn't work on the structured array, but does work on the individual fields.  That output could be indexed as a list of lists (it's not 2d).